# Java How to store/represent a String into long. Then from long to String

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

How would you store/represent a String into a long? Then jam it into an 8 byte array?

Things I've tried/working with

```
    String eidString = "Awesome!";
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    CharBuffer cbuf = buf.asCharBuffer();
    cbuf.put(eidString);

    byte[] eid = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(cbuf ??);
```

Attempt 2

```
    Long l = Long.valueOf("Awesome!");

    byte[] eid = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(l).array();

    long p = ByteBuffer.wrap(eid).getLong();

    System.out.println(p);
```

Attemp 3

```
String input = "hello long world";

byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
LongBuffer tmpBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asLongBuffer();

long[] lArr = new long[tmpBuf.remaining()];
for (int i = 0; i < lArr.length; i++)
    lArr[i] = tmpBuf.get();

System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lArr));
// store longs...

// ...load longs
long[] longs = { 7522537965568945263L, 7955362964116237412L };
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[longs.length * 8];
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(inputBytes);
for (long l : longs)
    bbuf.putLong(l);
System.out.println(new String(inputBytes));
```

Comment: Um, you realize the maximum string length you could do this with would be 8 characters, right?  Your 2 examples violate that.

Comment: Do you want to store a string of arbitrary length in a long? In other words is there a max length for the strings you want to work with?

Comment: how does java's utc conversion work like this then?

Comment: @mikeslattery, with compression more than 8 characters can be stored I think.

Comment: @russoue yes.. i'm completely clueless (obviously) on how to do this

Comment: @stackoverflow: [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)?  I think you mean some other acronym (UTF-8 or UTF-16 maybe?).

Comment: If the string length is 8 at max then String.getBytes() can be used IMO. I am assuming UTF-8 here.

Comment: @stackoverflow: A Java long can store 64 bits of data.  Therefore, you can store any value that has 64 bits of [information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit#Information_capacity_and_information_compression).  In practice, this would be 9 characters in 7-bit ASCII, or 4 characters in UTF-16 for the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane.

Comment: @mikeslattery: 4 characters, given that each is 16 bits...

Comment: @DanielPryden: You don't have to restrict yourself to the BMP. Any 4 UTF-16 code units would be okay... which would mean just two characters if they're outside the BMP, but they'd still be representable.

Comment: It'd probably help more to find out _why_ you want to convert a `String` into a `long` in the first place, since that's really not going to be possible in general.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Right.  But I think my comment is still accurate: if you have *characters* (in the Unicode sense) that are in the BMP, then you can store four of them in 64 bits.  If you have *code points*, you can also store four of them, but that may not be four user-readable characters.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Do you mean UTF-16 code units here? For example, it takes 2 UTF-16 code *units* to represent a single code *point* outside the BMP. It's not clear what you mean by "character" here, precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode your string as a number and reverse it.

- you have to determine the number of symbols you will need. e.g. 64 symbols need 6 bits. 32 symbols need 5 bits.
- this will determine maximum length of a string. e.g. for 6 bits => 64/6 = 10 symbols, for 8 bits => 64/8 = 8 symbols.  e.g. "hello long world" will not fit unless you assume not all a-z is available.

Once you have done this you can encode the symbols in the same way you would parse a 10 or 36 base number.  To turn back into a String you can do the reverse (like printing a base 10 or 36 number)

What is the range of possible characters/symbols?
 (you need to include a terminating symbol as the Strings can vary in length)

Answer (score 2):

If you accept the limited character set of:

```
 a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,
 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,
 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, , <-- space character
```

then you will have 63 symbols in your reduced alphabet ***`R`***. Each symbol can be mapped to a 6 bit representation (64 combinations unique combination of bits). There is an implicit 64th symbol which is the empty symbol used to mark the termination of the string, which should be represented by `0x00`. This leaves us with an alphabet ***`R`*** that maps to 6 bits as a bijection.

A `long` has 64 bits of information. Since `64/6 = 10`, this means that we can store a string with a length of up to 10 characters from alphabet ***`R`*** in a Java `long` variable.

It is worth noting that even though ***`R`*** is a reduced alphabet and we have a string length limit of 10, we can still express meaningful English phrases, converted them to a `long`, and back again!

**Java Code (64 bit mapping):**

```
public static long stringToLong(String s) {
  if(s.length() >10) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is too long: "+s); }
  long out = 0L;
  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i) {
    long m = reducedMapping(s.codePointAt(i));
    if (m==-1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmapped Character in String: "+s); }
    m <<= ((9-i)*6)+4;
    out |= m;
  }
  return out;
}

public static String longToString(long l) {
  String out = "";
  long m = 0xFC00000000000000L;
  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i,m>>>=6) {
    int x =(int)( (l&m) >>> (((9-i)*6)+4));
    if(x==0) { break; }
    out += mapping[x];
  }
  return out;
}


public static long reducedMapping(int x) {
  long out=-1;
       if(x >= 97 && x <= 122) { out = (long)(x-96); } //  'a' =>  1 : 0x01
  else if(x >= 65 && x <=  90) { out = (long)(x-37); } //  'A' => 27 : 0x1B
  else if(x >= 48 && x <=  57) { out = (long)(x-+5); } //  '0' => 53 : 0x35
  else if(x == 32 )            { out = 63L;          } //  ' ' => 63 : 0x3F
  return out;
}
public static char[] mapping = {
'\n', //<-- unused/empty character
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',' '
};
```

**Java Code (32 bit mapping):**

```
public static long stringToLong32(String s) {
      if(s.length() >12) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is too long: "+s); }
      long out = 0L;
      for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i) {
        long m = reducedMapping32(s.codePointAt(i));
        if (m==-1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmapped Character in String: "+s); }
        m <<= ((11-i)*5)+4;
        out |= m;
      }
      return out;
    }

public static String longToString32(long l) {
      String out = "";
      long m = 0xF800000000000000L;
      for(int i=0; i<12; ++i,m>>>=5) {
        int x =(int)( (l&m) >>> (((11-i)*5)+4));
        if(x==0) { break; }
        out += mapping32[x];
      }
      return out;
    }

public static long reducedMapping32(int x) {
      long out=-1;
           if(x >= 97 && x <= 122) { out = (long)(x-96); } //  'a' =>  1 : 0x01
      else if(x >= 65 && x <=  90) { out = (long)(x-64); } //  'A' =>  1 : 0x01
      else if(x >= 32 && x <= 34)  { out = (long)(x-5);  } //  ' ','!','"' => 27,28,29
      else if(x == 44 )            { out = 30L;          } //  ',' => 30 : 0x1E
      else if(x == 46 )            { out = 31L;          } //  '.' => 31 : 0x1F
      return out;
    }
public static char[] mapping32 = {
    '\n', //<-- unused/empty character
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
    'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    ' ','!','"',',','.' 
    };
}
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

Use this class for a more generalized conversions. It allows `Strings` of any *non empty* set of characters to be uniquely mapped uniquely to a `long` and converted back to the original `String` again. Simply define any character set (`char[]`) through the constructor and use the resulting object to convert back and forth using `str2long` & `long2str`.

**Java `StringAndLongConverter` Class:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringAndLongConveter {

  /* .,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,., */
  /*   String <--> long ID Conversion   */
  /* `'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`'`' */

  /* --<[ Class Members ]>-- */
  // Don't re-arrange, order-dependent initializations

  private final char[]  CHAR_MAP;
  public  final int     NUM_ACTUAL_CHARS;
  public  final int     NUM_MAPPED_CHARS;
  public  final int     BIT_COUNT;
  public  final int     MAX_NUM_CHARS;
  public  final long    ROLLING_MASK;
  public  final long    FORMAT_MASK;
  public  final long    MIN_VALUE;
  public  final long    MAX_VALUE;
  public  final Pattern REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR;

  public StringAndLongConveter(char[] chars) {
    if(chars == null  ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot Pass in null reference"); }
    if(chars.length==0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot Pass in empty set"     ); }
    CHAR_MAP             = setCharMap(chars);
    NUM_ACTUAL_CHARS     = CHAR_MAP.length;
    NUM_MAPPED_CHARS     = NUM_ACTUAL_CHARS+1;
    BIT_COUNT            = calcMinBitsNeeded();
    MAX_NUM_CHARS        = calcMaxPossibleChars();
    ROLLING_MASK         = calcRollingMask();
    FORMAT_MASK          = calcFormatMask();
    MIN_VALUE            = calcIDMinVal();
    MAX_VALUE            = calcIDMaxVal();
    REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR = createRegExValidator();
  }

  /* --<[ Dynamic Initialization Calculation Helper Methods ]>-- */

  //Remove duplicates
  private final char[] setCharMap(final char[] chars) {
    char[] tmp = new char[chars.length];    
    int dupes = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<chars.length; ++i) {
      boolean dupeFound = false;
      for(int j=0; !dupeFound && j<i; ++j) {
        if(chars[i]==chars[j]) {
          ++dupes;
          dupeFound = true;   
        }
      }
      if(!dupeFound) { tmp[i-dupes] = chars[i]; }
    }
    char[] out = new char[chars.length-dupes];
    if(dupes==0) { out = chars; }
    else {
      for(int i=0; i<out.length; ++i) out[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    return out;
  } 
  // calculate minimum bits necessary to encode characters uniquely
  private final int calcMinBitsNeeded() {
    if(NUM_MAPPED_CHARS==0) { return 0; }
    int val,tmp,log;
    val = NUM_MAPPED_CHARS;
    tmp = Integer.highestOneBit(val); // returns only the highest set bit
    tmp = tmp | (tmp-1);              // propagate left bits
    log = Integer.bitCount(tmp);      // count bits (logarithm base 2)
    return ((val&(val-1))==0) ? log-1 : log;
    //return one less then bit count if even power of two
  }
  //Calculate maximum number of characters that can be encoded in long
  private final int calcMaxPossibleChars() {
    return Long.SIZE/BIT_COUNT;
  }
  //Calculate rolling mask for str <--> long conversion loops
  private final long calcRollingMask() {
    long   mask = 0x0000000000000001L;
    for(int i=1; i<BIT_COUNT;     ++i) { mask  |= mask << 1; }
    for(int i=1; i<MAX_NUM_CHARS; ++i) { mask <<= BIT_COUNT; }
    return mask;
  }
  //Calculate format mask for long input format validation
  private final long calcFormatMask() {
    //propagate lest significant set bit in rolling mask & negate resulting value
    return ~(ROLLING_MASK | (ROLLING_MASK-1));
  }
  //Calculate min value of long encoding
  //doubles as format specification for unused bits
  private final long calcIDMinVal() {
    return 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL & FORMAT_MASK;
  }
  //Calculate max value of long encoding
  private final long calcIDMaxVal(){
    char   maxChar    = CHAR_MAP[CHAR_MAP.length-1];
    char[] maxCharArr = new char[MAX_NUM_CHARS];
    Arrays.fill(maxCharArr, maxChar);
    return str2long(new String(maxCharArr));
  }

  //Dynamically create RegEx validation string for invalid characters
  private final Pattern createRegExValidator() {
    return Pattern.compile("^["+Pattern.quote(new String(CHAR_MAP))+"]+?$");
  }

  /* --<[ Internal Helper Methods ]>-- */

  private static boolean ulongLessThen(long lh, long rh) {
    return (((lh ^ rh) >> 63) == 0) ? lh < rh : (0x8000000000000000L & lh)==0;
  }

  private long charMapping(final char c) {
    for(int i=0; i<CHAR_MAP.length; ++i)
      if(CHAR_MAP[i]==c)
        return i+1;
    return -1;
  }

  /* --<[ String <--> long Conversion Methods ]>-- */

  public  final String long2str(final long n) {
    String out = "";
    if (ulongLessThen(n,MIN_VALUE) || ulongLessThen(MAX_VALUE,n)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Long Outside of Formatted Range: "+Long.toHexString(n)); }
    if ((FORMAT_MASK & n) != MIN_VALUE)                           { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Improperly Formatted long"); }
    long m = ROLLING_MASK;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_NUM_CHARS; ++i,m>>>=BIT_COUNT) {
      int x =(int)( (n&m) >>> ((MAX_NUM_CHARS-i-1)*BIT_COUNT));//10|10 0111
      if(x >= NUM_MAPPED_CHARS) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Formatted bit mapping: \nlong="+Long.toHexString(n)+"\n masked="+Long.toHexString(n&m)+"\n i="+i+" x="+x); }
      if(x==0) { break; }
      out += CHAR_MAP[x-1];
    }
    return out;
  }

  public  final long str2long(String str) {
    if(str.length() > MAX_NUM_CHARS) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is too long: "+str); }
    long out = MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); ++i) {
      long m = charMapping(str.charAt(i));
      if (m==-1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmapped Character in String: "+str); }
      m <<= ((MAX_NUM_CHARS-i-1)*BIT_COUNT);
      out += m; // += is more destructive then |= allowing errors to be more readily detected 
    }
    return out;
  }

  public  final boolean isValidString(String str) {
    return str != null && !str.equals("")               //null or empty String
       &&  str.length() <= MAX_NUM_CHARS                //too long
       &&  REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR.matcher(str).matches(); //only valid chars in string
  }

  public final char[] getMappedChars() { return Arrays.copyOf(CHAR_MAP,CHAR_MAP.length); }

}
```

Have fun encoding & decoding `String`s & `long`s

Comment: This works great, but what if I only need the characters A-Z? I tried reducing the amount of required bits to 5, and therefore the maximum length of a string to 12, but I can't figure out how to generalize the algorithms here.

Comment: @Makario I will look into this for you later today

Comment: @Makario I have updated my answer with 32bit encoding option. Compare the two algorithms to understand how they work in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

To parse a String into a Long, can use the Long wrapper class.

```
String myString = "1500000";
Long myLong = Long.parseLong(myString);
```

To stuff it into an 8-byte array...

```
long value = myLong.longValue();
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
   long mask = 0xFF00000000000000 >> (i * 8);
   bytes[i] = (byte) (value & mask);   
}
```

This example is big endian.

If you're *encoding* a String into a long, then you can do something like:

```
String myString = "HELLO";
long toLong = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
   long c = (long) myString.charAt(i);
   int shift = (myString.length() - 1 - i) * 8;
   toLong += c << shift;
}
```

This hasn't been tested. There might be a few things wrong with it.

Comment: But I need to store characters such as "Hello" into the long. You cannot do that with the wrapper class. Long.parseLong("hello") wont work

Comment: @stackoverflow: **Why** do you "need" to do this?  It's like saying, "I need to be able to park my car in my backpack, but the zipper doesn't go that far!"  Well of course it doesn't -- why do you expect that your car will fit in your backpack in the first place?

Comment: @DanielPryden well I ask the question to see the solutions. I'm carrying and alpha-numeric ID inside a long which comes across on a UDP packet. I'm just the decoder - not the encoder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. String has a method called getBytes(). It do the convert for you directly. Call the following method with parameter "Hallelujah"

```
public static void strToLong(String s) throws IOException
{
    byte[] bArr = s.getBytes();
    for( byte b : bArr)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + b);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.write(bArr);
}
```

The result is

```
 72 97 108 108 101 108 117 106 97 104
Hallelujah
```